# Android ANR CRASH Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50200010 }

Tags: java, android, exception, android-anr-dialog

I am getting crash report error using on my google play console. Here is code where i am getting error. Please help me to sort out the problem

> Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
>   flg=0x50200010 }

```
try {
            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (bannerList.size() > 0) {
                            if (activity != null) {
                                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            int position = bsPromotion.getCurrentSlidePosition() - 1;
                                            if (position < 0 || position > 4) {
                                                position = 0;
                                            }
                                            tvBannerText.setTag(position);
                                            tvBannerText.setText(bannerList.get(position).title);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            }, 0, 500);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: I'm also getting this crash. Do you have any update?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `deadObjectException` so you have to resolve it.

**DeadObjectException** - The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.

**Solution:** Override your service's onDestroy() method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

As you are using web api in your fragment so sometimes that will sending multiple request on server and in terms of response you are getting @null.

Comment: **SCREEN_ON** Intent probably isn't related to DeadObjectException.

Answer (score -1):

Test your application using Firebase Test Lab, you can find it's documentation from below link:

[Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/)

I am sure, it will give possible results of your app crashes and you can find them in your code.

Hope it helps.
Thanks.